# How to get rid of search.safefinder malware

Tags: windows-10, malware

At the time of updating my kmplayer software, "Safe Finder" malware has been installed in my computer. I have searched for solutions for removing it and I got many solutions. But, probably they are little bit old and that malware `Safe Finder` is more strong now. That's why, none of those solutions worked for me. There is no sign of this application in control panel and browser extensions. Still http://search.safefinder.com/ is coming at the time of starting browsers.

I `reset` my chrome. That malware was gone from chrome start page, but came back again after restarting my pc in chrome. I `refresh`(reset) even `reinstall` firefox. But, that malware are still staying in firefox. I followed the tricks of going properties of chorme/firefox browser and delete the unknown words in `Target` field. But, there were no extra words rather than default!

[image]

This malware is even hiding this directory `C:\Users\Users\Local App` and don't open the web pages regarding solutions of removing this malware. Specially Firefox and Chrome are affected by this malware. Microsoft Edge, Safari etc are free from it.

How can I get rid of this malware?

Comment: [Remove Search.SafeFinder.com virus (Removal Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/search-safefinder-com-removal/)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I followed that link, not worked for me

Comment: So running Malwarebytes didn't get rid of it for you?

Comment: @user1896653 - I find it hard to believe that the half dozen programs suggested in that thread didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run the adw cleaner from "https://toolslib.net/downloads/finish/1/"

Then it will ask to restart the system....

Go ahead and restart and see if the issue is resolved or not.

Then if the issue still persists then download the Hitman Pro from " http://dl.surfright.nl/HitmanPro.exe"

Run it and activate it as a trial.

Let it run completely. It does take time to check all the infections.

After that process all the threats and restart.

Then last of perform the clean boot.

Open run --> Type "msconfig" --> Go to services tab --> Check Hide Microsoft Services. --> Then select disable all.

Next come to advanced and select disable all for windows 7 else it will ask you to open windows task manager and disable the ones which have high impact.

Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you explain what these tools are and what they do? This seems rather spammy to me.

Comment: These are the adware removal tools and are meant to remove the infections... Do not panic as they are absolutely safe...

Comment: @bwDraco Hitman Pro is a real anti-adware solution, and the link does go to the right place, but I've never heard of the first one. Two VirusTotal scanners [balk at it](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/97b725460d95e4b466134d75745f5b9c66113da11670c855c5f93cd3d67ca6a2/analysis/)

Comment: where is this option, "disable all for windows 7" @Ankur Srivastava?

Comment: Well this option comes when you write msconfig and then hit enter in the run box and go to the Advanced as well as in services tab.
Do remember that in services first hide the Microsoft Services by placing a check mark and then select disable all however under Advanced Tab you can disable all by selceting the disable all tab at the bottom right.